# Input argument "b" is undefined

Tags: matlab

i am new in matlab and search everything. I am writing a the function. i could not able to understand why this error is comning :"Input argument "b" is undefined." . shall i intialise b =0 ? whereas it is the parameter coming from input console. my code:

```
function f = evenorodd( b )
%UNTITLED2 Summary of this function goes here
%zohaib
%   Detailed explanation goes here
%f = b;%2;
f = [0 0];
f = rem(b,2);
if f == 0 
    disp(b+ 'is even')
else 
    disp(b+ 'is odd')

end
```

console:

```
??? Input argument "b" is undefined.

Error in ==> evenorodd at 6
f = rem(b,2);
```

Comment: Alas, your "console" part is incomplete. Especially, the call is missing. If you do `evenorodd` or `evenorodd()`, `b` is indeed undefined. Instead, you should call `evenorodd(1)`, `evenorodd(2)`, `evenorodd(any_variable)` or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, this is what you are trying to do:

```
function f = evenorodd( b )

f = rem(b,2);
if f == 0 
    fprintf('%i is even\n', b)
else 
    fprintf('%i is odd\n', b)

end

=======================

>> evenorodd(2);
2 is even
```

1. No need to initialize `f` as `[0,0]`.
2. In MATLAB, you cant concatenate a number and string with `+` operator. Use `fprintf`.
3. The above function `evenorodd` takes one argument (integer) and returns 0 or 1.

Comment: Seems so. But this is quite the same... Especially, your answer doesn't deal with the `Input argument "b" is undefined` part.

Comment: thanks. that is working now. but clear me how it is returning? like in c++ we write "return" statement. how this is returning???

Comment: you can use `return` statement anywhere in the function to return. The returning value is specified by `f` in the above function (`function f =` part). So if you return the function without setting `f` value, it will give you an error.